# Trouble accessing JSON object as a Constant in a Javascript Module

Tags: javascript, json, constants, es6-modules

I have Javascript module named constants.js with the following in it:

```
const coreObjects = {
    activity: {
        objectName: 'activity',
        table: 'activities',
        pk: 'activity_id',
        recordTypeID: 'A'
    }
}
export { coreObjects }
```

I'm trying to reference the 'table' attribute of this constant with the following in a separate script file:

```
let constants = await import('./constants.js');
let actvityTable = constants.coreObjects.activity.table;
```

And I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'activity')
```

Any thoughts on how I get this to work?  Thanks!

When I change to the following it doesn't generate an error but is not giving me the specific access to the 'table' field that I was looking for:

```
let actvityTable = constants.coreObjects
```

Comment: Works fine for me ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-worker-7j79x7?file=/src/index.js. How exactly are you executing this?

Comment: Hey Phil, thanks for the quick reply!  That CodeSandbox link isn't loading for me. It just says "loading".  Any chance you could confirm the link works for you?  Thanks!

Comment: I first ran it locally using Node.js. The CodeSandbox just has your exact code and it works without issue

Comment: Here Phil, I gave the CodeSandbox a try I (my first time using an online tool) and still get the error.  Would love to see your copy that seems to be working.  Thanks!    https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/goofy-elbakyan-yxxqkk?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.html%3A8%2C7

Comment: Well you're missing the `await` which is clearly in your question above. Is it in your actual code though?

Comment: Hey Phil, thanks again for the reply.  I removed the await because Codesandbox was generating a syntax error on it ("Await is a reserved word").  It is used in my code.  I get the same error in my code those when I include it.  If you have any other thoughts or are able to share the working version you had in Codesandbox I would appreciate it.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you access my CodeSandbox link yet? I wrapped it in an async IIFE, ie `(async () => { ... })()` but in my Node.js test I used nothing else but the code in your question

Comment: Wrapping it in (async () ==> {})() worked.  Thanks!